# Forward all network destinated packets to the OS virtually installed on VMWare

Tags: windows, vmware-player

here is my problem. I start my computer on a Windows session. I launch VMWare Player and start an Ubuntu session. I would like that all packets, on Windows, which are destinated to the network are sent to the virtual Ubuntu. Then, Ubuntu will forward all these packets to the real network card to be sent through the network.

How can I do this please ? What should I configure on Windows/VMWare ?

Thank you.

Comment: there's an interesting thought - using the hosted VM as the host's firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to set up packet forwarding on the Ubuntu VM (with the VM set up using bridged networking) and set your Windows computer to use the Ubuntu VM as a gateway.

Googling Ubuntu packet forwarding or gateway should give links like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=183994) or [this one](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/96509133/m/954005971931) to help with the configuration.

Or you can download a specialized distro meant for doing firewalling and routing like [shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/) for running in a VM, depending on what you're trying to do. Google for a linux router distribution and there should be a nice list of them available to try. Might make configuration a little easier (and requirements a little smaller on the VM).

Comment: Nail on the head.

Comment: if you're interested in a non-Linux-based solution, you could also try m0n0wall - http://m0n0.ch/wall/